# Add Custom Created EventHandler in XAML, WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

i've created a custom event in my ViewModel.

Its not a function, its an EventHandler like MouseLeave, MouseEnter, etc. That's what i need in my implementation.

Here it is:

```
public event EventHandler SpinEllipses;
```

Now I need to assign it in xaml, but I don't know how. And Bindind does not work in this case. I tried it. I have this StoryBoard that triggers when the MouseEnter Event is fired. But i wan to replace this MouseEnter event to my SpinEllipses event. How can I do this in the MVVM way?

Thx.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedTransform"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                    From="0.0" To="360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys. I gave up on that idea. My goal was beeing able to spin my Sllipse and disable that spinning. Using a button or anything.

To accomplish that, I've created a custom Ellipse Controll, and added the animation inside that custom controll. By doing that, I got what I want.

This series of videos thought me how to create a custom controll

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YJqoZFAGPA&list=PLA8ZIAm2I03gNGsQQYHmb7nK8VIt9EI9u&index=1

Its important to understand how to create one.

To rotate my sllipse, I used this code:

```
var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 360, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
                var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
                ellipse.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
                ellipse.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, doubleAnimation);
```

To stop rotation:

```
var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
                ellipse.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
                ellipse.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
```

And I call my custom controll in xaml like this:

Note that I've created a DependencyProperty that is a boolean, to stop or start the spinning

```
<Canvas Margin="50 50 50 50">
                <Customs:Ellipses SpinEllipse="{Binding Spin1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Canvas>
```